# Select from temp table fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm inserting data into a temp table and querying the temp table fails

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)

SET @SQLQuery  = 'SELECT  Top 100 *
                  INTO #tempTable
                  FROM ' + @origDB + '.dbo.' + @origTable + ' o WITH (NOLOCK) ' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

and when I try to query the temp table , like so

```
select * from #tempTable
```

I get the following error :

> Invalid object name '#tempTable'.

Comment: when I replace #tempTable with tempTable it does work , and data is populated in tempTable

Comment: Are you selecting from #tempTable within the same session?

Comment: Better than manually adding square brackets you should use QUOTENAME. And that NOLOCK is likely going to cause you problems unless you are ok with missing and/or duplicate at random times. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Testing this sql in SQL managment studio

Comment: The reason for the error is because your temp table is out of scope once you leave dynamic sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courtesy of [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1dd6a408-4ac5-4193-9284-4fee8880d18a/invalid-object-name-tmptable-whenselecting-from-temporary-table-made-using-into-from-execstr?forum=transactsql)

> The problem that you have is with the scope. The TEMP table is creatd at the scope of the EXEC() method and hence it is not available after the function returns. To fix this, create your temp table before calling EXEC() and use an INSERT INTO instead of SELECT INTO.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the scope of a temporary table is limited to the session context in which it is created - a stored procedure runs in its own context.

You *could* use a global temporary table `##tempTable`, but it's generally a bad idea as it would be available to other sessions than the one creating it.